# Can Chrome v41 Inspector be docked to side?

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

With the latest version of Chrome (v41), I seem to only have bottom and pop-out window options. Is there a way I can dock the Web Inspector to the side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a little icon on the right of the Inspector that docks to the side. See the attached screenshot[image: dock to side icon]

If you only see the bottom or pop out icon perform a long click on the icon to turn it into a drop down menu.